# Make cannot be called from script without sourcing the script

Tags: bash, makefile, mingw, subshell

I want to call the make command from a bash script in a MinGW bash shell. However the script seems to know "make" only when I call the script using source:

build.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
make all
```

Calling
**source build.sh**
from the terminal works: The target *all* is built.

Calling only
**build.sh**
from the terminal results in

**./build.sh: line 2: make: command not found**

Why do I have to source the script to have a working make command?

Comment: Are you using bash in your terminal as your default shell?

Comment: What does `which make` tell you?

Comment: Use `/usr/bin/make` or better check `which make` and use `$path/make all`

Comment: Are you using the MSYS2 bash shell, or which shell exactly are you calling this from? Is the location of `make.exe` listed in the `PATH` environment variable (check with `echo $PATH`)?

Comment: Seems like it might be some kind of shell configuration issue.  Edit the script to add `echo $PATH` before you invoke make, then source it and run it and see what the difference is.

Comment: I am using Git bash ("%PROGRAMFILES%\git\usr\bin\bash.exe" -i -l) in Windows Terminal 1.10.2714.0)

Comment: which make results in "which: no make in ( ... my whole $PATH ... )", no matter if I call it from the command line or from build.sh (with and without source)

Comment: I've checked $PATH. It is exactly the same when I echo it from the command line, when I echo it from the script, and when I echo it from the sourced script.

Comment: Searching my whole HDD, it turns out that I don't have any executable make.* at all anywhere on my PATH or in any subfolder of %PROGRAMFILES%\git. So, how is it possible that make is a known command in my environment?

Comment: MinGW is old, install Ubuntu on Windows 10 or Windows 11 and try the same script